# Handling MsalUiRequiredException in AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf request

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-ad-msal

I am trying to chain authentication through 3 services using MSAL. I am populating the `ClaimsIdentity` with additional claims after the token has been validated. The user authenticates with ServiceA scopes. ServiceA then calls ServiceB using AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf. ServiceB then calls the Microsoft Graph API using AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf.

This works great if the user has consented to ServiceA and ServiceB. However, if the user has not consented to ServiceB, `MsalUiRequiredException` is thrown.

I can avoid consent from ServiceA to ServiceB by using the "Authorized client application" in the Azure Portal. However, I cannot use that feature on the Microsoft Graph API. I also do not have the option to use admin consent.

How should I let ServiceA know that the user hasn't consented to ServiceB? The token has already been validated for ServiceA, so I'm not sure what I would even do. I can't include scopes from two different authorities in a single request. Do I send two authentication requests and not use AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf?

Here is the code I'm using to authenticate using Microsoft.Identity.Client.

```
    public async Task PopulateClaimsAsync(ClaimsIdentity identity, JwtSecurityToken token, string redirectUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(token.RawData, _jwtAssertionType);
            var app = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder.Create(_authentationOptions.ClientId)
                        .WithAuthority(_authentationOptions.Authority)
                        .WithRedirectUri(redirectUrl)
                        .WithClientSecret(_authentationOptions.ClientSecret)
                        .Build();
            app.AppTokenCache.SetBeforeAccess(OnBeforeAccess);
            app.AppTokenCache.SetAfterAccess(OnAfterAccess);

            var result = await app.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(new string[] { "User.Read" }, userAssertion).ExecuteAsync();
            var graphToken = result.AccessToken;

            var me = await _graphApiClient.GetMe(graphToken);
            //snip
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            //Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS65001: The user or administrator has not consented to use the application with ID
            //??
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you ever figure this out?